# i18n for selectOneMenu witrh SelectItemGroup

Tags: jsf, internationalization, selectonemenu

In my JSF application with Primefaces 5.3 I have a SelectOneMenu with SelectItemGroup entries where the entries need to be translated.

My XHTML snippet:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="status" value="#{bean.status}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.statusItems}"
        var="status"
        itemLabel="#{bundle[status.label]}"
        itemValue="#{status}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Here I use `"#{bundle[status.label]}"` to translate but always the labels as generated in the Bean class are shown and never the translated strings from my resource bundle!

My Bean class snippet:

```
public class Bean {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("status.offerPhase");
        g1.setSelectItems(
                new SelectItem[]{
                        new SelectItem("untreated", "status.offerPhase.untreated"),
                        new SelectItem("In Progress", "status.offerPhase.untreated.inProgress"),
                });

        SelectItemGroup g2 = new SelectItemGroup("status.ongoing");
        g2.setSelectItems(
                new SelectItem[]{
                        new SelectItem("Order received", "status.ongoing.orderReceived"),
                        new SelectItem("Ongoing construction site", "status.ongoing.ongoingConstructionSite"),
                });

        SelectItemGroup g3 = new SelectItemGroup("status.completed");
        g3.setSelectItems(
                new SelectItem[]{
                        new SelectItem("Finished", "status.completed.finished"),
                        new SelectItem("Archived", "status.completed.archived"),
                });
        statusItems = new ArrayList<>();
        statusItems.add(g1);
        statusItems.add(g2);
        statusItems.add(g3);
    }

    private List<SelectItem> statusItems;
    public List<SelectItem> getStatusItems() {
        return statusItems;
    }
}
```

It does also not work if I don't use SelectItemGroups like this:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        statusItems = new ArrayList<>();
        statusItems.add(new SelectItem("untreated", "status.offerPhase.untreated"));
        statusItems.add(new SelectItem("In Progress", "status.offerPhase.untreated.inProgress");
    }
```

Using enums like this works:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="status2" value="#{bean.statusEnum}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.statusEnum}"
        var="status"
        itemValue="#{status}"
        itemLabel="#{bundle[status.name()]}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

public enum Status {
    STATUS_UNTREATEFD, STATUS_IN_PROGRESS, STATUS_COMPLETED
}
public Status[] getStatusEnum() {
    return Status.values();
}
```

Bundle Properties:

```
STATUS_UNTREATED=Untreated
STATUS_IN_PROGRESS=In Progress
status.offerPhase.untreated=Untreated
status.offerPhase.inProgress=In Progress
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`When using `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` as model value, the `var` would represent its `value`, not the `SelectItem` itself. The item value is already represented as `value` of `SelectItem` instance itself, and the item label is already represented as `label` of `SelectItem` instance itself.

In other words, when providing a list or array of `SelectItem`, you do not need `var`, `itemLabel` and `itemValue` at all.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.statusItems}" />
```

As to i18n'ing the labels, grab/inject the resource bundle `#{bundle}` in bean and do the job over there. E.g.

```
new SelectItemGroup(bundle.getString("status.offerPhase"));
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between by Application#getResourceBundle() and ResourceBundle#getBundle() in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927717/difference-between-by-applicationgetresourcebundle-and-resourcebundlegetbund)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your fast response! Using bundle.getString() solved my problem partially, because I get the translated strings for the inital locale. But I have a LocaleSwitcher in my JSF page, where I can switch the language and than the translated selectItems remain always the same!
How can I handle this Locale switching?

Comment: Pass locale while getting bundle, or inject bundle. See "See also" link for detail.

Comment: I solved the translation now also with the LocaleSwitcher. Reason was that I created the SelectItems in a Producer class with ApplicationScope and therefore the SelectItems where created only once!